# MFRC522 RFID Python3 Script won't start: No such file or directory

Tags: python, rfid, pi

I have the problem that the Python Scripts for the MFRC522 RFID-Reader won't start. I couldn't find any solution to this problem

I tried following this tutorial: https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-rfid-rc522

when starting the script I get this error:

```
pi@pi-d339203c:~/pi-rfid $ python3 Read.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Read.py", line 5, in <module>
    reader = SimpleMFRC522()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mfrc522/SimpleMFRC522.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.READER = MFRC522()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mfrc522/MFRC522.py", line 131, in __init__
    self.spi.open(bus, device)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: May help to post the contents of Read.py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue - turns out I had SPI disabled - it's required for the MFRC522.  If you're using Raspbian, run

```
sudo raspi-config
```

and enable it in there under Interfacing options -> SPI then reboot.

To check if spi is indeed enabled, run

```
lsmod | grep spi
```

the output should look something like this:

```
spidev                 20480  0
spi_bcm2835            20480  0
```

If you get no output, then spi is not enabled.
I believe you can also enable it by editing `/boot/config.txt`

Answer (score -1):

You don't say that you are using windows or linux,
but the error message is the format used by windows IOError messages

Your path starts with "/usr/local." which is not on windows, rather linux. So you just need to fix the path to match your OS.